# Why does my function always return 1?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, if-statement, return-value

I'm writing a function that's supposed to check whether there is a winner or not in a game of "noughts and crosses", or "three in a row".

The game works by first drawing out 3 x 3 squares in the command prompt. The user then moves the cursor between the squares, and presses enter to place an "X". The next selected square gets an "O" placed in it, and then an "X" again, and so on. After turn 5 (the first possible turn there could be a winner) the program checks if there is a winner after every turn, and if none is found after 9 turns (when all squares have something in them) the program declares a draw.

However, the function I've written to check for a winner always returns 1 when it's called, which means there is a winner (X more specifically, since thatäs the one that made the last move). Therefore the game ends on turn 5, no matter what the squares contain.

Here is my code:

```
int control(char p[3][3]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)    //Checks if any of the horizontals have 3 of the same markers in a row
        if (p[i][1] == p[i][2] && p[i][2] == p[i][3]) 
            return 1;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)    //Checks if any of the vertical columns have 3 of the same markers
        if (p[1][i] == p[2][i] && p[2][i] == p[3][i])
            return 1;
        else if (p[1][1] == p[2][2] && p[2][2] == p[3][3])    //Checks if top left, middle and bottom right squares have the same marker
            return 1;
        else if (p[3][1] == p[2][2] && p[2][2] == p[1][3])    //Checks if the top right, middle and bottom left have the same marker
            return 1;
        else               //If none of the above have the same 3 markers, the game keeps going
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try running through your function step-by-step, through a debugger or even just with pen and paper?

Comment: And while debugging, check what's in each of the boxes if they don't have an X or an O.

Comment: You cannot index the 4th row or column in a 3 by 3 matrix.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)` is wrong when the size of the arrays is only `[3][3]`.

Comment: `c` is a `0` base array, not `1` base. The array is from `[0][0]` up to `[2][2]`, not from `[1][1]` up to `[3][3]`.

Comment: well, do you know that a C array **is  always zero based** (the first index in the array is `0`) and the last **is always the number of cells minus one**?  you have `for` loops runing for values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` (this is _four array elements, and not three_) and you check array elements with indexes `1`, `2`, and `3` (that should be `0`, `1` and `2` instead) etc.  Check this, you'll get probably a surprise :)  (you have the code crowded of this kind of buggies, so you have to correct this, before more checking)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing in a 3x3 array (with indices 0, 1 and 2 in each dimension), but in your loops you are iterating 4 times (indices 0, 1, 2 and 3). Try `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` in your loops instead, as your loops will now check values beyond the boundaries of the `p` array, and if you are unlucky the contents of that memory causes your control function to return 1.

Finally, I think the final else-block should not be in the loop, but rather outside of it: If both loops have run and you have not returned yet, you can safely return 0, but you wouldn't want to return a 0 prematurely before you have checked all your verticals.

Here is the function with the changes to the indices and the diagonal checks and final else-block fished out of the second for-loop:

```
int control(char p[3][3]) {
    int i;

    /* Check horizontals */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if (p[i][0] == p[i][1] && p[i][1] == p[i][2]) 
            return 1;

    /* Check verticals */
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        if (p[0][i] == p[1][i] && p[1][i] == p[2][i])
            return 1;

    /* Check diagonals */
    if (p[0][0] == p[1][1] && p[1][1] == p[2][2])
        return 1;
    if (p[2][0] == p[1][1] && p[1][1] == p[0][2])
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```